# React-Native - Global component instead of using redux?

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm looking for a way to have a global component, so that my webview in it wont reset every time i switch over with Router to that parent's component.

Any ways to make save webviews data with redux so it won't reset each time, or a global component?

Comment: Try to add some relevant code. Redux state is global and it is only your code (actions and reducers) what changes the redux state. The state is not reset automatically. Only a browser refresh (or a native application restart) will reset it it, because it loads your application from scratch.

Comment: React Context API

Comment: @lavor You cannot store components with redux.

Comment: @Hobey823 what do you mean by "to store components"? You should store state of your components, not the components.

Comment: You should probably read my question.

Comment: You can try to use localStorage with react-native

Comment: Bad to store components on the local storage.